# Definition of motivic/coming from geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a projective smooth connected curve, $S\subset X$ is a finite set of points and $U=X\setminus S$.

I encountered the following definiton:

> We say a $\mathbb Q$-local system $\mathcal F$ on $U$ comes from geometry (or in fancier language, being motivic) if there is a projective morphism $f:Y\to U$ and a natural number $i$ such that $\mathcal F$ is a subquotient of $\mathbf R^if_*\mathbb Q $.

I'm confused that why do we need to consider subquotient? And what kind of subquotient does it mean? (we know there is a Hodge filtration for $\mathbf R^if_*\mathbb Q $, does it mean taking quotients in this filtration?) Why is "subquotient" important?

Comment: Subquotient = sub-object of a quotient, in the category of local systems.

Comment: @abx OK, but why subquotients but not $\mathbf Rf_*\mathbb Q$ itself?

Comment: @Richard becase you want your category to be stable for equations and subjects (and, possibly extensions). In others words, you look for an abalean subcategory.